reStructuredText: Fix section/headline level when including file
I have a couple of dozen .rst files that are all loaded from a main index.rst file via .. include: file.rst.
Now I want to restructure the TOC and move some files onto a different headline level - but do not want to change all the headline levels in all the files.
The main file has section level 1, all included files use section level 2. I want to introduce some level 2 headings in the main file, and include files with level 2 headings as level 3 without actually changing their file content (there are too many files).
Can I somehow "fix" or change the section levels when including files?
Example
Old structure

Main title

File 1 title
File 2 title



index.rst:
Main title
==========

.. include: file1.rst
.. include: file2.rst

file1.rst:
File1 title
-----------

Content

New structure

Main title

Subtitle

File 1 title


File 2 title



index.rst:
Main title
==========

Subtitle
--------
.. include: file1.rst
   :FIXMEsomeOptionToChangeSectionLevels:

.. include: file2.rst


By default, "include" inserts the content of the to-be-included rST file into the input stream and then continues parsing. Consequently, for the parser, there is no difference to one large input document.
There is no "magical" option that re-writes the section title adornments before
inserting a file into the input stream.
However, because there is no fixed relation of adornment style to section level, you need to adapt at most half of the included files:
If more than half of the files should move to a lower level, you can introduce a new adornment for the second level. If all files are moved one level down,
only the main document needs to be changed. For example:
New structure

Main title

Subtitle

File 1 title
File 2 title


second subtitle

File 3 title





Main title
==========

Subtitle with a hitherto not used adornment style
`````````````````````````````````````````````````
.. include: file1.rst
.. include: file2.rst

second subtitle
```````````````
.. include: file3.rst

...


There is also an experimental workaround using the provisional "parser" option of the "include" directive. While it is intended for the inclusion of files in other input formats (markdown, Docutils-XML), it can also be used with the reStructuredText parser:
Subtitle
--------
.. include: file1.rst
   :parser: rst

In this case, the included file is parsed into a "dummy document" whose child elements are appended to the main document tree.
Warning:

Using "include" with the "parser" option may generate an invalid document structure and lead to unspecified behaviour or strange errors!
The releationship between namespaces in the "dummy document" and the main document is not specified and may change in future releases.

